# parametric integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, integration

Is there a mistake in the bottom of page 5 of this document? [INTEGRATION: THE FEYNMAN WAY](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} e^{be^{ix}}= e^{ix}e^{be^{ix}}$$ instead of $ib e^{be^{ix}}e^{ix}$? thank you very much. Also, i want to ask if there is any general rule to choose the parameter?

Comment: it seems you are right since $\frac{\partial e^{f(b)}}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial f(b)}{\partial b} e^{f(b)}$

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no mistake.  Imagine that $y=e^{i x}$.  Then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} e^{b e^{i x}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial b} e^{b y} =y e^{b y}$$

Now put $y=e^{i x}$ and you get the stated result.

Comment: so i'm correct and the document is wrong? this is excatly what i get, but in the document, it says $\partial e^{be^{ix}}/ \partial b = ibe^{be^{ix}} e^{ix}$.

Comment: @cooper: if the document says that, then it is wrong, wrong, wrong.